# Як перекласти "web browser"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Російською перекладають "интернет-обозреватель".

Як це українською зробити? Цікавить використання саме слова з українським походженням. Не англіцизма.

Comment: -1, бо це запитання не показало власної спроби запитувача знайти відповідь.Також не завадать навести контекст. За цих умов зніму -1 і проголосую за перевідкриття питання.

Comment: Є такий сайт: [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/brauzer) — там користувачі намагаються створити суто українські еквіваленти для запозичених термінів. Слід зазначити, що не всі варіанти, що їх пропонують там, доречні чи десь вживаються (навпаки, здається, що значна частина запропонованих перекладів уживаються хіба що в уяві їхніх авторів). Однак, по-моєму, дуже корисний сайт, щоб подивитися, які варіанти взагалі хоч комусь приходили в голову (тобто не «що доречне чи використовується», а «що теоретично можна придумати»). Можна додавати свої варіанти.

Comment: Microsoft [тяжіє до англіцизму «браузер»](//www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=browser&langID=Ukrainian&Source=true&productid=All+Products). Стільничне середовище [KDE](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE) — до словосполучення «переглядач інтернету». Веб-браузер Google Chromium [називає себе «веб-переглядач»](//translations.launchpad.net/chromium-browser/translations/+pots/chromium-browser/uk/+translate?batch=10&show=all&search=browser). А [тут](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/56) ми намагаємося зібрати докупи різні способи, якими можна шукати застосовувані в програмах переклади

Comment: (але білішість із цих способів доволі незручні; здається, лише Microsoft дозволяє робити прямий пошук по всій базі з єдиної веб-сторінки і без інсталяції додаткових програм).

Answer (score 3):

[У Англійсько-українському словнику](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=web%20browser&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> **web browser** = веб-браузер {?}, веб-переглядач {?}, веб-навігатор {?}

В [СУМ online (1-8 томи)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=197844&page=264)

> **ВЕБ-БРА́УЗЕР**, а, ч., інформ. Те саме, що бра́узер. *Веб-браузери є програмними засобами для роботи з гіпертекстовими документами, за
>   допомогою яких можна завантажувати файли з мережі* (з наук.-попул.
>   літ.); *У деякі веб-браузери вже вбудовано поштові програми та
>   редактори гіпертекстів* (з Інтернету).

Comment: Дякую, не знав про такий словник

Comment: Vydno vlyw moskowsjkoji: _[w = у](/q/3048/585)_ zamitsj _в_.